# How do you get all the contents from a tkinter "multiple select" Listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

You can see here that I am creating a tkinter `ListBox` and populating it with 3 items. All I need to do is be able to record what the user has selected when they press the button!

I know that when you click the Button, **`bigListbox.curselection()`** gets the indexes of the items correctly and inserts them into the `show` label.

But I need to actually collect the currently selected strings and save them to a file upon clicking send.

```
def showSelected():
    show.config(text=bigListbox.curselection())


bigListbox = Listbox(rootWindow, selectmode="multiple")
bigListbox.pack()



# Load workstations from file
bigArr=["MYHSS", "MY", "MORE", "Aloysius"]

myIndex = len(bigArr)

for index in range(0, myIndex):
    bigListbox.insert(myIndex, bigArr[index])


Button(rootWindow, text='Send', command=showSelected).pack(pady=20)


show = Label(rootWindow)
show.pack()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.get()` of `Listbox` to get the string at specified index:

```py
def showSelected():
    # create a comma separated list of selected items
    items = ", ".join(bigListbox.get(idx) for idx in bigListbox.curselection())
    show.config(text=items)
```